# Problema ao fechar app no Android quando muitas telas estão abertas

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-10

Antes de iniciar o App preciso fazer algumas validações, por isso criei uma tela de Splash onde as mesmas são feitas.  Então para evitar que o usuário volte para a tela de Splash quando ele pressiona o voltar do aparelho em determinadas telas eu fecho a aplicação usando `MainActivity.finish` (também tentei usando o método `Terminate` do serviço descrito neste link http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXApplicationService).
Porém no Android uma Aplicação não é encerrada totalmente, ela fica na pilha de tarefas para que caso o usuário decida reabrir ela inicie rápido.
O PROBLEMA É:
Quando foram abertas até umas 4 telas funciona como o esperado, agora se foram abertas mais do que isso quando tenta abrir ela de novo depois de fechar fica na "tela branca do Android", trava e não vai.

Comment: Por que na SplashActivity ao chamar a a próxima Activity você não da Finish() nela ? assim o usuário não terá como voltar para ela de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Vou testar desta forma, obrigado.